# error : can't read .... no such variable in TCL script using "after"

Tags: variables, scope, global-variables, tcl

I am working in a TCL automation environent at my workplace.
I'm trying to run a delayed command in my script using "after".
The problem i encounter is that when i try to specify commands with variables inside a code block under an "after" , the vars are not recognized and i get an error message.
I'll quote the relevant parts of the code.

```
proc test_script1 {{bh0 0} ...more vars....} {
.
.
.
after [expr 20000]   {
   set some_value[ ns1::probe_TCP_connections $bh0 $main_duration 1  15]    }

puts "the value i got is $some_value"
}
```

And i seem to get an error: 
can't read "some_value": no such variable

Can anyone suggets what is the problem , and how to oversome it?
thx

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm)? The way you wrote the command makes it so that the command for `after` is made to run at the designated delay while continuing with the script. So `puts "the value i got is $some_value"` is being executed before the variable is set. Additionally, your `set` inside the `after` block looks suspicious.

Comment: you are right about the puts being executed right after.I'll clarify , lets say i add a delay before the puts , aith another "after". the interpreter still doesn't recognize the variable

Comment: Also, in the manual: "The command will be executed at global level (outside the context of any Tcl procedure)" so you will have to fetch the variable from the global level, and there's quite a few ways to do that.

Comment: First of all thanks. I'll be thankful if you could elaborate on that.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the values of local variables with the help of `apply` (and it's advisable to use `list` to build callbacks when they get even slightly non-trivial). Since the body of an `apply` is a lambda expression with its own scope — a little nameless procedure — you have to use `global` in it to access state that will persist, and in any case `after` callbacks are called from the global namespace always (since the mechanism doesn't know how to keep arbitrary stack frames around for the duration of the *asynchronous* operation).

```
after 20000 [list apply {{bh0 main_duration} {
    global some_value
    set some_value [ns1::probe_TCP_connections $bh0 $main_duration 1 15]
}} $bh0 $main_duration]

global some_value
vwait some_value
puts "The value was changed to $some_value"
```

It's possible to get even more sophisticated, especially in Tcl 8.6 which has a coroutine system that can be used to hide the complexity of using continuation passing style programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `proc` that will do something similar to what you're trying to do:

```
proc foo {} {
    # Make 'a' available to both the global scope and local scope
    global a
    # This is to check the current level
    puts "Current level: [info level]"
    # The command to be run in 500 ms, and I have added another check for the level
    after 500 {puts "Current level: [info level]"; set a 100}
    # Wait for further execution until the global variable 'a' changes
    vwait a
    # Prints a
    puts "Value of \$a: $a"
}
```

The output of the above will be:

```
Current level: 1
# After 500 ms, the below will print
Current level: 0
Value of $a: 100
```

When you use `after`, the variable `a` is being created in the global scope, that is not accessible to the proc unless explicitly given access. One of the simplest ways is to first make sure that `a` within the proc is accessible both globally and locally, with `global` (level 0).